# Should spectral normalization be passed as a kernel_regularizer or kernel_constraint argument in a Dense layer?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I do not quite understand the difference between the parameters `kernel_regularizer` and `kernel_constraint` of the [`Dense` layer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dense?version=nightly), in TensorFlow 2.0.

I am trying to apply Spectral Normalization to my network. What is the difference between the two?

My intuition tells me that Spectral Norm is a constraint. But what difference would that make if I passed it as a `kernel_regularizer` argument?

Comment: Unfortunately, this site is not appropriate for programming issues. See https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic for more details. Stack Overflow is the most appropriate site for these issues. I will migrate your question to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***"My intuition tells me that Spectral Norm is a constraint.  But what difference would that make if I passed it as a kernel_regularizer argument?"***

Yes, you're right. Spectral Normalization is a constraint.

**Here is the difference between the regularizer and constraint:**

At each training step, the weights will be passed to the **regularization function** to compute the regularization loss,
which will be added to the loss to get the final loss used for training.

While

The **constraint function** will be called after each training step, and the layer's weights will be replaced by the constrained weights.

There is a huge difference between the two so I think using **Spectral Normalization** as a regularization will not work as what it does as a constraint.
You may want to create your custom regularizer function instead to produce the result you wanted to achieve.